# Jenkins Agent-container unable to run Docker commands on host due to 'permission denied' error

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up Jenkins master in a docker container on one host and a Jenkins Agent on another host also in docker. I cannot get the agent to run docker commands on its host. I keep getting permission denied errors.

My compose files are:

host:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    restart: unless-stopped
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
      - 50000:50000
    container_name: jenkins-master
    volumes:
      - data:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
    deploy:
      resources:
          limits:
            memory: 2G
          reservations:
            memory: 256M
volumes:
  data:
```

agent:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/ssh-agent:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 23:22
    container_name: jenkins-agent2
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
    environment:
      JENKINS_AGENT_SSH_PUBKEY: MYKEY
    deploy:
      resources:
          limits:
            memory: 2G
          reservations:
            memory: 256M
```

I'm able to connect the master to the agent fine. I'm able to kick off a free style project, but using

```
docker volume create somename
```

Throws an error. I've noticed jerkins is using a user named "jenkins" in the container. I assume the issue is that user isn't in the docker group on the host. The "jenkins" user the container is using does share a UID/GID with a user on the host that is in the docker group. I've got no idea how to give the "jenkins" user the right permissions or how to change jenkins to use another user.

here is my shell command and the error:

```
echo $USER
docker volume create testvol
```

```
[create docker volumes] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins10140641630471278856.sh
+ echo jenkins
jenkins
+ docker volume create testvol
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/volumes/create": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

I've tried to set the UID and GID in the compose file, but that only changes the value for the root user. I verified the jenkins user in the container and a user on the host (that has access to docker) have the same UID and GID. On the host I have a user "Local_Admin" that is in the docker group, can run docker commands and it has the same id's as the jenkins user in the container.

Comment: `- /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker` There were multiple questions where people keep mounting executables from host. Is this from some kind of manual? Why people keep doing that? `I assume the issue is that user isn't in the docker group on the host` Great! So add him to that group. Did you? What happens when you added? What group is it? `I've tried to set the UID and GID in the compose file, but that only changes the value for the root user.` I do not understand that part. root user always has uid=0 gid=0, you can't change it. You can change the user with `user: different_user`.

Comment: I'm very inexperienced with Linux but here are my best answers. 

I mount the executable because otherwise I cannot run docker commands. 

Host has Local_User and a docker group. The container only has the jenkins user. Since the docker group isn't part of the container I literally am not sure how to add that user the group. 

UID stuff TBH this still a little unclear to me. I tested again with adding:

`environment:
      PUID: 1000
      PGID: 1000`

to the docker compose and your right. I must have been tired and been looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: `otherwise I cannot run docker commands` Sure. Like on any other system, you have to _install_ docker to be able to use it. Create a dockerfile and run package manager to install docker. Using executables from host may result in incompatibilities. Or may be fine. `how to add that user the group` There are two options. One is to create a dockerfile and add the group and add the user to the group. The other is to use `user: 1000:1000 group_add: - the_docker_group_of_host` for example in the docker-compose file. `with adding: environment:` Environment are just normal variables, do not affect user

Comment: The only way I was able to get his to work was by editing /etc/group. I changed the docker group id from 101 to 1000. The container wouldn't start if I tried to use `user:` or `group_add:`